# Intersection Observer using querySelectorAll throws a TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I'm getting stuck on a Intersection Observer problem. Using `document.querySelectorAll('.entry')` throws a TypeError: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Changing `document.querySelectorAll('.entry');` to `document.querySelector('.entry');` solves the issue and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

**The basic HTML structure:**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="content-container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="entry">Some content here on each entry</div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body
</html>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
const blog = document.querySelectorAll('.entry');
const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } 

    else {
      console.log(entry);
    }
  });



}, options);


observer.observe(blog);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue happens because [`IntersectionObserver.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe) can only observe one `targetElement` but using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you are passing a NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. Thus you are having an issue with it, but [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only gives you first matched element thus there is no issue when you use this.

You can resolve this issue by looping through all elements in the list and observe each of them indivdually like:

```
const blogs = document.querySelectorAll('.entry');
blogs.forEach(blog => observer.observe(blog));
```

Comment: So, now I'm getting another error when trying to perform: `blogs.classList.add('entry-animation');`. I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined". I believe that's because the const "blogs" is not available in the function? How would you fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Simple. Try: `blogs.forEach(blog => blog.classList.add('entry-animation'));`

Comment: I believe this is appending the class to all blogs and they animate at the same time, but we're getting closer!

Comment: @palash, would you have any insight on how to prevent all classes to be added at once? When the page refreshes, all divs with a class name of `entry` all have `entry-animation` loaded at the same time. The intersection observer is triggering everything at once. Pardon my ignorance, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Please create a new question for this, so that we can target one issue at a time and also post the question link here. I will try to look into it if I get time later on. Also, if possible add a small demo in that question. You get more responses to a question if you can reproduce the issue using a simple demo.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @palash. Here's the new question. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046574/)