# Why is Intersection Observer adding class to all observed elements upon intersection of first element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, intersection-observer

Pardon my ignorance, as I'm learning. I'm working on getting `div`s with the class of `.entry` to animate upon intersection with the Intersection Observer by adding the class of `.entry-animation` to them.

I've never worked with selecting all elements and animating before. Upon the first intersection, all elements simultaneously animate. What am I doing wrong?

**Here's the demo:**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/muLxq73p/7/)

**Here's the HTML**:

```
  <div id="content-container">
    <div class="content">

      <div class="entry">
        <h2>
          Title of Post 1
        </h2>
        <p>
          Some content here on each entry
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h2>
          Title of Post 2
        </h2>
        <p>
          Some content here on each entry
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h2>
          Title of Post 3
        </h2>
        <p>
          Some content here on each entry
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h2>
          Title of Post 4
        </h2>
        <p>
          Some content here on each entry
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h2>
          Title of Post 5
        </h2>
        <p>
          Some content here on each entry
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="entry"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
body {
  background: #FFF;

}

.entry {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px #cecece;
}


.entry-animation {
    animation: 2s fadeIn-1;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(20%);
        opacity: 0;
}
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

**Here's the JS:**

```
const options = {
  threshold: 0.4,
};

const blogs = document.querySelectorAll('.entry');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {

  entries.forEach((entry) => {

    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    }
    blogs.forEach(blog => blog.classList.add('entry-animation'));


  },options);
});

blogs.forEach(blog => observer.observe(blog));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily fix this issue by replacing:

```
blogs.forEach(blog => blog.classList.add('entry-animation'));
```

with

```
entry.target.classList.add('entry-animation')
```

inside `entries.forEach()` loop. The issue here is basically we just need to add the animation class to only the elements which are in view using `entry.target`, instead of adding them to all at once.

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z28oesaL/)

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you for all of your help, and stay safe!