# Javascript, intersection observer to detect every time image scrolls into viewport

Tags: javascript, scroll, intersection-observer

I want to be able to detect each time an image tag comes into a view in a long article with lots of images.

The code I have so far looks like this, but it only seems to detect the first time the image element comes into view.

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        console.log('Element has just become visible in screen');
}, { threshold: [0] });
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#main-container"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually resolved this using this answer: [Intersection Observer using querySelectorAll throws a TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042672/intersection-observer-using-queryselectorall-throws-a-typeerror)

This is the working code which uses a for loop to detect every image, not just the first:

```
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true) {
    console.log('Element has just become visible in screen');
}
}, { threshold: [0] });


const blogs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
blogs.forEach(blog => observer.observe(blog));
```